# Controlling 3 axis brushless gimbal motors

Tags: raspbian, gpio, i2c, gui, readwrite

I am new to using the Raspberry Pi 3 and trying to control brushless [gimbal motors](http://www.etecpower.com/html_products/PM3505-encoder-gimbal-motor-93.html) with encoders to "look around"

Using I2C, I have gotten them to read its orientation from [BaseCam's Simple BGC GUI](https://aerialpixels.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/1.jpg). (mine includes yaw)

How do I go about utilizing the data from the GUI to send to the Pi?
I want the Pi to constantly output the orientation of the gimbal.

Comment: I'm also looking to do the same thing.  Hopefully someone will respond with an answer.